# Syncing two sheets, while being able to hide different data

Tags: microsoft-excel, sync, spreadsheet, duplicate

I'm pretty new to excel- so please bear with me. 
I have created a spreadsheet to organize gear by serial numbers and by who has it. This list is getting updated multiple times daily as gear shuffles regularly. 
I have gear that is assigned and unassigned. On the main sheet I have all the data, the way I want it to be organized.

What I'm trying to do is duplicate this sheet, so that both sheets automatically keep the same data at all times, but on the first sheet I can hide all the unassigned gear, and view only the assigned gear, and then be able to narrow it down in groups using the hide function heavily.

On the second sheet I want to be able to hide all of the assigned gear, and all the columns of gear that have no unassigned gear. 
End result will be that as gear is moved between individuals or is unassigned entirely, I make that adjustment on one sheet and the data stays the same on both, but the way I view that same sheet is different on both.

If I'm making no sense just let me know and I'll try to explain again more clearly.

Comment: Provide some screenshot or some examples

Comment: you want to filter one sheet to show assigned only and the other unassigned only?

Answer (score 1):

Just do linked tables with filters. To link the tables, just have the second sheet reference the first sheet (sheet1!A1) and apply a filter on the "assigned" column

To link the data, see [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/403552/microsoft-excel-2010-how-to-reference-a-table-to-another-sheet) and to apply filters, highlight the headers and go to data - filter (dependent on your version of excel) and then choose the drop down on the "assigned" column and select the values you want to see