# Microsoft Excel 2010 How to reference a table to another sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I am using Excel 2010.

I got a sheet name "March"
[image: March Sheet]

I would like to duplicate it[This is a **table**] (with reference / link) to another sheet called "Summary"
which included January, Feb, and March.

In the summary tab I would add another column called "Month" and will duplicate the value "March" or their tab month.

I did some research on it, they said copy and paste special with link, but I can't find it.

I need to reference the whole table, just in case any change add / remove the row of the table, the summary still will update it. Is there any solution with this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft Excel is not able to reference a `Table` with reference / link to another sheet. It only worked with `Range`.

With range you can reference like this.
Sheet1!$A$1

But it is not possible with `Table`.

Answer (score 5):

You copy and then right click `paste special` and `link` is at the bottom, it's a button in 2010

[image]

Alternatively, it should be in your paste menu when you right click:
[image]

It's the one that looks like a chain (link) or an infinity symbol

Comment: How about if the original table, added record, I think this link does not work what I ask about the feature, and add another column reference the month.

Comment: I'm sorry, could you be more clear in your question?

Comment: I would like to archieve 2 objectives. First, I would like to duplicate a table from a sheet - S(SOURCE) to another sheet - D (Destination). When S did a update(add/delete), D also will update the data/record/row. Lets say Sheet S is from the month of March. Once I duplicated it to Sheet D. I would like to add another column named "Month" and have records of March. The Sheet D will be the summary for many month. Hope I have my question clear. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, I only work on normal **range**, but my object is **table**, so this solution is not applicable to me. Any more solution?

Answer (score 3):

The answer from @Raystafarian does not work when selecting the whole table. For some reason Excel doesn't allow the paste with links. However it can be done by copying it twice, first time with only headers and second time with only data. I don't get that.

Comment: This should be a comment to the item in question.

Comment: but still it is very useful to know of this frustrating lack of proper functionality

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround to this... albeit an ugly one.

You can achieve the desired effect by first importing the Table from the Excel Source File into an Access DB (using linked tables for example), then importing that Access Table into your final Excel Destination file.

However, if you want things to update automatically, it requires that you write come small code to open the Access DB and update the files there, before the data is correct in your destination file.