# Paste link into Table disallowed?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, copy-paste, cut-and-paste

I am trying to use the Copy / Paste Link (ALT+ESL), but it does not appear to be an option when pasting into a Table.

Is this a known limitation of Excel (using 2013)?  If so, is there a better work around than doing the Paste Link outside of the Table and then Cut / Paste into the Table?

**Paste Link is missing in the Table**

[image: paste link into table]

**Same cell is available to paste link outside Table (far right icon)**

[image]

I did a [search here on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/search?q=%5Bexcel%5D+paste+link+table) but was unable to find a direct match.  This [question is similar](https://superuser.com/questions/403552/microsoft-excel-2010-how-to-reference-a-table-to-another-sheet) but is more about linking to an entire Table and not pasting into a Table.

Answer (score -1):

what i did after nearly punching myself in the face in frustration, ='Data List'!A3 . 
data list is my sheet name.

but then i wanted it to update constantly and data list holds a table and i can't table, so i dragged the formula down a row of boxes so that they'd match even if data list got updated.

if you do the same, you'll realise that the empty boxes in data list gives you a 0 with the formula.

so i did this =IF(ISBLANK('Data List'!A3),"",'Data List'!A3)
interpretation: if data list box a3 is empty, don't give me anything. if it's not, give me what data list a3 has.

not very savvy, but this is what i did with my noob excel skills.

Comment: I can't see how this post is related to the question